# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'cancellation' of

Tags: c#, xunit

I have this interface which I am creating XUnit testing.

```
Task PostMessage(CancellationToken cancellation);
```

This is my XUnit code

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenAValidMessagePosted_ThenReturnStatus20()
    {
        // Arrange (Seed)         

        // Act
        var result = await _service.PostMessage();

        // Assert
    }
```

I have compilation error here in `PostMessage()`. How do I supply CancellationToken to this method in Xunit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a placeholder `CancellationToken`, pass in `CancellationToken.None`:

```
var result = await _service.PostMessage(CancellationToken.None);
```

However, in my experience, you don't want to risk deadlocking your entire test suite, so I generally prefer to pass a real cancellation token that will automatically cancel after a couple of seconds. You can accomplish this by using a `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var result = await _service.PostMessage(token);
```